# How to change original (unchangeable?) ICCID/SIM card serial from an AVD

Tags: sim-card, imei, emulators, 2.3.3-gingerbread, avd-manager

I need to have several running Android Virtual Devices, so have been trying to change the original ICCID/SIM card serial from an AVD and all the solutions I found oblige me to alter QEMU's code (see here: http://blog.codepainters.com/2010/11/20/android-emulator-patch-for-configurable-imei-imsi-and-sim-card-serial-number/).

I'm using:

- Windows 7;
- Java 1.7;
- Android Studio 1.2.1.1;
- Android SDK Tools 24.3.1.

I'm emulating:

- Android device with Gingerbread 2.3.3 (API 10).

Does anyone got a solution? Thank you!

Comment: I would also be interested by the answer. I'm looking for something pretty the same; I want to modify the certificate embeded in the virtual SIM card OR add mine into the ACL of the SIM. Did you found something ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I solved it a long time ago by editing by cloning the original QEMU and editing the hex of the cloned ones. What happens is that the ICCID/SIM card information is inside the hexadecimal code of the QEMU, hence I had to search for the ICCID (I recall that it was something like 00000...), change it and load the cloned-and-changed QEMU for a specific AVD.

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for the reply ! By editing hex, you mean that you edited the AVDManager.exe file ? I've seen some subjects where people took AVDManager source and recompiled it after make some changes, but it seems sources are not available anymore.